# Conditionally do a partial refresh on an XPage

Tags: javascript, xpages, partial-page-refresh

I have an application that runs a timer script that does a click on an action button when it times out. The action button is hidden by display:none. on the action button I do a partial refresh on panelButtonBar from the onClick event. This all works great except part of what the onClick event does is sets a viewScope variable based on the condition of the document. The viewScope variable is vsIsLocked and can be either true or false. If the value is true I don't want the panelButtonBar refreshed. I created a field that does nothing called dummyField and added the following to the definition of the partial refresh:

```
(viewScope.get("vsIsLocked")) ? "dummyField" : "panelButtonBar"
```

by putting dBar.info statements in the code that is by the onClick of the action Button I know that it is running on schedule, I also know that the value of vsIsLocked has changed from true to false, but the panelButtonBar does not refresh. As I said if I take the conditional statement out and just do a partial refresh of panelButtonBar the refresh works, the conditional partial refresh does not. I believe my js correct. I tried:

```
(viewScope.get("vsIsLocked")) ? "" : "panelButtonBar"
```

but then the partial refresh seems to run as a total refresh.

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle to illustrate this further? Greetings from one Bill F. to another.

Comment: @BillF. to another - not sure what you mean. Everything works the code for a conditional refresh. In the dialog for Select the Element to refresh I select Secfify element ID and then instead of entering panelButtonBar and select the little diamond and enter the js above. it is pretty simple vsIsLocked is either true or false if it is true refresh the dummyField that really does nothing (just a place holder) if it is false refresh panelButtonBar. I could leave it always doing the partial refresh on panelButtonBar but when is true there is no reason to do so.

Comment: He's referring to http://jsfiddle.net/ which is a great way to test and share purely client-side web code. Since this particular issue is server-side behavior, that's not applicable in this instance, but it's a good tool to be aware of.

Comment: P.S. Since event handlers are also components, they support the `rendered` attribute. If the button you're hiding via CSS is inside your partial refresh target, and you compute the `rendered` attribute of its event handler, when you programmatically "click" the button, nothing will happen if `rendered` evaluates to false, because the click event will not have been registered.

Comment: @Tim all of the components in this case are "hidden" by using display:none NOT the "rendered" property. Everything works as expected if I put "panelButtonBar" explicitly in the partialrefresh property, except I get a whole bunch of needless partial refrshes done. Seems to revolve around the formula for a partial refresh. The onClick event sets vsIsLocked correctly but the partial refresh formula does not seem to fire, at least not correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You might be a little caught in "what gets refreshed when". The `(viewScope.get("vsIsLocked")) ? "dummyField" : "panelButtonBar"` sits in your hidden button and gets computed when that button refreshes. When you "press" the button however you either refresh the dummyField or the panelButtonBar, but not the button itself. So your condition doesn't get evaluated.

You can try put your hidden button into the panelButtonBar or target your refresh at something that includes both.

**Update**
The target property is only evaluated on page load, so you would need to have one button each for your refresh targets hard wired and compute the rendered property. So when it refreshes a different button is sent to the browser each time. You could use a custom control with a parameter array for the targets, so you only have one control in your UI

Comment: The button is rendered but but hidden by display:none. I don't consider not "rendered" as hidden, I consider it as not there, If I want to "hide" something from the user I use "display:none", I do not believe the "rendered" should ever be equated with hidden. The other part of the equation is that if I put "panelButtonBar" explicitely in the partial refresh it does exactly that. The issue that I'm trying to stop is a bunch of partial refreshes.

Comment: Even when I have the formula in the partial refresh the "click" event triggers on schedule, so I believe the issue revolves entirely around the issue of the partial refresh formula. I setup a test situation where vsIsLocked was true when the user opened the document (ie the document was locked), then I released the lock on the document. Next time the click event ran vsIsLocked was false but the partial refresh did not refresh panelButtonBar.

Comment: Remove the formula from the partial refresh and replace it with "panelButtonBar" repeat the above precess. Works exactly as I want it to, but does a needless partial refresh every "n" seconds. Just want to strip out the needless overhead.

Comment: actually the button is inside the "panelButtonBar"

Comment: If I recall correctly the refresh targets are only evaluated on page load, so you can't switch them on the fly. So you might want to travel down the approach Tim suggested

Comment: that would be a pain if that is true, but not sure it is correct. it would appear that I might have it working, but can't see that I have really changed anything. I hate it when that happens.

Comment: It would appear that you are correct that the partialrefresh target is only refreshed on the page load. So it would appear that there is no way to dynamically refresh different element based on changed values at the document or scope level. Bit of a bummer. I have my process contained in a custom control so if I make a property on the custom control the partial refresh field, then have two of the same custom control and have them rendered based on a formula that might get around this issue, but then is the partial refresh target determined by which custom control is rendered at page load?

Comment: But I added dBar.info statements into my partial refresh target and the formula is executed with every scheduled onClick event, and sets the return correctly, but seems to have no effect.

Comment: Your workaround lies in the button! Have one button each for your refresh targets hard wired and compute the rendered property. So when it refreshes a different button is sent to the browser each time. You could use a custom control with a parameter array for the targets, so you only have one control in your UI

Comment: I guess I'm just going to have to let it do the partial refresh even though I know the conditions that a partial refresh is unnecessary. Messed around with two different action buttons and had the script switch which one got the click event but that did not work either. It is really too bad that the partialRefresh target is set on the page load. I have a couple of additional ideas but have to move on to something else for a while.

Comment: Your client side script shouldn't "mess which button get the click". Select the button based on a class and use the rendered property to display only one of them.